# Cannot read a file using parse_ini_file

Tags: php, ini

I can't load the data from an ini file using parse_ini_file.  It is able to read the file using file_get_contents, but fails when using parse_ini_file. The ini file is:

```
[names]
me = Robert
you = Peter

[urls]
first = "http://www.example.com"
second = "https://www.w3schools.com"
```

The code is:

```
echo file_exists($iniFile), "<br>";
echo file_get_contents($iniFile), "<br>";
echo "print_r parse result---->";
print_r(parse_ini_file($iniFile));
$data = parse_ini_file($iniFile);
echo "<br>this is data-me---->", $data['me'], "<br>";
echo "this is data---->", $data, "<br>";
if(empty($data)){
    HHelper::logItA($folder . "/Errors", $folder . "_ini", $key . " file empty");
    die("\nNo data in {$key}, iniFile {$iniFile}\n");
}
```

and the output is:

```
1
[names] me = Robert you = Peter [urls] first = "http://www.example.com" second = "https://www.w3schools.com"
print_r parse result---->
this is data-me---->
this is data---->
No data in EventImport/test.ini, iniFile s3://configs.hamlethub.com/EventImport/test.ini
```

I can't figure out why this will not read into the array.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems curious it would fail silently. I assume it's returning a boolean false since the print_r is empty. If that's the case, it's definitely failing, though not helpfully. The documentation states that as of 5.2.7, false is returned as a result of a syntax error. Maybe strip the file down to just a single, simple definition and see if that returns anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disregard my comment above, your ini file is syntactically fine and parses without issue on my machine.

If the file is located on S3, as implied by the value of the `$iniFile` variable in your error output, then the function `parse_ini_file` may not be what you need. A comment on the function's documentation notes the function does not seem to work for remote files: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php#37293.

That said, it's still possible to achieve what you're going for, here's what I'd try:

Since you can retrieve the contents of the file with `file_get_contents` off of S3, you can parse the text that is returned. You can use the function `parse_ini_string` to do the same parsing that `parse_ini_file` would have done, and return the expected associative array.

```
$ini = file_get_contents($iniFile);
$data = parse_ini_string($ini);
print_r($data);
```

That should do the trick.

Here's the documentation for `parse_ini_string`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-string.php

It's worth at least noting that the idea of having a remote ini file strikes me as a security risk, depending on what the contents of the ini file are used for, so make sure you lock the permissions of this file in AWS' ecosystem down tightly. The reason the `parse_ini_file` function probably doesn't contact remote machines may just be for security reasons (though they may have just decided never to implement the functionality due to low demand).

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a to, you saved me a lot of headaches.  I would have never have thought of that. I have the S3 file opened as a stream and did not know there would be a difference. Thanks for the tip on security as well. it is fairly locked down as the S3 is only open to this server.